# kubernates few clarifications on some topics

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to k8s and i want to have few clarification on below questions, please let me know ur thoughts

1. Does persistent volumes claims are confined to single namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Does persistent volumes claims are confined to single namespace ?

Persistent Volume Claims(PVC) is bound to namespace. PVC must exist in the same 
 namespace as the Pod using the claim

> 2. How many pod networks can we have per cluster ?

Default maximum of 110 Pods per node, Kubernetes assigns a /24 CIDR block (256 addresses) to each of the nodes.

> 3. Which namespace contains the infrastructure pods ?

Generally kube-system

> 4. Does all objects are restricted to single namespace ?

No, not all objects are restricted to single namespace. You can create objects in different namespaces.

> 5. Does container offer a persistent storage that outlives the container ?

If you use PV/PVC then your storage must be persistent

6. What is the smallest object or unit(pod or container or replicaset or deployment) we can work with in k8s?

A Kubernetes pod is a group of containers, and is the smallest unit that Kubernetes administers.

> 7. does a deployment use a persistent volume or a persistent volume claim ?

You need to use PVC in deployment, in volume section like following

```
volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: <pvc name>
```

> 8. With deployment config spec which strategy(recreate or rollingupdate) allows us to control the updates to pod ?

Recreate will terminate all the running instances then recreate them with the newer version. Rolling update follows defined strategy of how many instance will be down and recreate at a time.

> 9. How can we start local proxy which is useful for development and testing ?

You can use [port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

> 10. Pod can have multiple ip address?

single pod have single ip address. details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#networking)

Comment: ,thanks for the answers ..
for below question ,does a deployment use a persistent volume or a persistent volume claim ? we need to select any one either PV or PVC ? 
2.Does all objects are restricted to single namespace ? its true or false .3.How many pod networks can we have per cluster ? we have 4 choices (0,1,2,3,4,)

Comment: I updated answer. what it mean by ```we have 4 choices (0,1,2,3,4,)```

Comment: i cant see ur updated answer

Comment: For number 7, ```You need to use PVC in deployment```.  for number 2, ```No, not all objects are restricted to single namespace. ```

Comment: can please share your answers for below questions aswell ,

Comment: please share your answers for below qs,1.which among the following service types spreads packets among Pods in a deployment automatically ?(a.NodePoer, b.Loadbalncer, c.PacketSpreader d.none of the above).
2.which is the suggested object for deploying and scaling an applications?(a.Pod, b.Container,c.Deployemnt,d.service)3.k8s uses REST api driven architecture 
4.for mangaing dedicated services such as storage,network following components are developed,choose all that apply?(a.volumne-controller-manager, b.kube-controller-manager,c.cloud-controller-manager,d.storage-controller-manag

Comment: ,5.kube-public is a namespace readable by all ?(true or false)
6.what are the specs declared in deployment choose all that apply?(a.Replicaset,b.pod configuration,c.ReplicationController,d.Lables,e.none of the above)
7.context is a combination of choose all that apply?(a.cluster credentails, b.user credentails ,c. network credentails, d.none of the above)
8.the settings whcih are set to false by default are. choose all that apply?(a.namespace,b.podAffinity,c.nodAffinity,d.label)9.which k8s agent watches the API server for configuration changes and iptable updates ?

Comment: Your comment is not relatable to your questions. Can you add those in seperate question?

Comment: not able to add a new question, i tried it but its not allowing me to open new question, can u please share ur answers here .. need those answers urgently

Comment: thanks for your answers..

Comment: ,, below are the last set of question and will not be asking any other question further in this thread .. please share your answers ...

Comment: 10.how can u start a local proxy which is usefull for dev and testing?( a.kubectl proxy, b.kubeadm proxy, c.proxy-start, d.none of the above)
11.kube-proxy creates and manages networking rules to expose the container on the network ?( true or false)
12.labels are used to determine which pods should receive traffic from a service ?(true or false)
13.a sidcar is a container dedicated to performing a helper task ?(true or fase)
14.the /kube/config file containes ?choose all that apply?(a.endpoints , b.SSL keys, c.COntexts,d.none of the above)

Comment: 15.how many pod networks can you have er cluster ?(a.1,b.2,c.3,d.4,e.0)
16.what object connects other resources together and handles ingress and egress traffic?(a.pod,b.controller,c.service,d.etcd)
17.each node in the cluster runs ?choose all that apply?(a.kubectl,b.kube-apiserver,c.kube-proxy,d.kube-nodeagent)

Answer (score 2):

1. A PersistentVolumeClaim (kubectl get pvc) is confined to a Namespace. A PersistentVolume (kubectl get pv) is defined on cluster-level. Each namespace can access the PV which are not "Bound"
2. You have to install one CNI (Container Network Interface) like calico or flannel. There you will specify a PodNetworkCIDR e.q. 10.20.0.0/16. Then the IPAdressManagement of e.q. Calico will split that network into some smaller networks. Each Kubernetes Node get's his own Network from the 10.20.0.0/16 Network.
3. If you mean the Kubernetes "Infrastructure" it's mostly deployed to kube-system. To deploy you're own stuff like Monitoring, Logging, Storage you can create your own Namespaces
4. No not all Objects are bound to a Namespace. With `kubectl api-resources` you will get an overview.
5. There are a lot of storagetype (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes). But if you not specify any volumes (PV) which are persistant, your files which are written in a container are gone if the container restarts.
6. A Pod is the smallest Unit which can be addressed. A Pod could contain multiple container.
7. A Deployment describes the state of the Pod. It's recommended to use a Deployment. You can start a Pod without a Deployment, but if you delete the Pod it will not be restarted by the Kubelet. (The following command creates a Pod without a Deployment: kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 --restart=Never). For Storage, you would specify the PVC in the Deployment. But you have to create that PVC before.(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)
8. Exactly, For e.q. a MySQL you would use recreate, for httpd you would use rolling.
9. What do you mean with `local proxy` For local development you can have a look at `minikube`?
10. No, a Pod has only 1 IP.

Comment: thanks for the answer